# How to iterate through a list of the pointers of objects in C++

Tags: c++, stl

I'm learning how to use C++ STL and algorithms.
Currently, I want to iterate a list of the pointer of objects.
This is my approach so far:

```
for (list<Course*>::iterator it = this->course_list.begin(); 
        it != this->course_list.end(); ++it){
            cout<<it->course_code<<endl;
}
```

this is a method inside a class, `course_list` is a member of it and it's a list of the pointer of another class called Course. By doing this, I think "it" now is the pointer to each Course object in the list. `course_code` is a member of the class Course.

I tried

```
it.course_code;
```

or

```
it->course_code;
```

both didn't work.

How do I access the `course_code` with "it"?

Thanks for help.

Comment: You have to dereference twice. `(*it)` is a `Course*` pointer, and `*(*it))` is a `Course`. So `(*it)->course_code` would be the `course_code` member of the `Course` object.

Comment: @NathanPierson Do you mean by `(*(*it))->course_code` ? I can't use It either, it says it needs pointer type

Comment: @NathanPierson I've just fixed my problems. It works with `(*it)->course_code` Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the iterator functions as a pointer to the underlying data. Meaning lets say I had a vector of integers like below

```
vector<int> test = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for(auto it = test.begin(); it != test.end()l ++it){
    cout << *it << endl;
}
```

This will do what you desire, you basically need to dereference the iterator to get to the underlying data. So  in your case to access the course_code replace

```
cout<<it->course_code<<endl;
```

With

```
cout<<*it<< endl;
```

Comment: I dont think you read my answer, I said to replace it->course_code with *it